# how can function object be used as a function pointer when the function's argument is function pointer

Tags: c++

I have a question related to function objects or functors in C++. I understand that function objects can substitute function pointers in many cases, such as some algorithms in STL. However, I do not know how to invoke function object if the function's argument is function pointer. For example:

```
          class ClassA
        {
        public:
            void operator()(std::string &name)
            {
                std::cout<<"Class A"<<std::endl;
            }
        };

        class ClassB
        {
        public:
            void operator()(std::string &name)
            {
                std::cout<<"Class B"<<std::endl;
            }
        };

        void testClass(void(*fun)(std::string&), std::string &name  )
        {
             (*fun)(name);
        }

            void funClass(std::string &str)
            {
                std::cout<<"hello C "<<str<<std::endl;

                   }
```

It is very easy to invoke the `testClass` function if I only use function pointer:

```
std::string str= "hello.txt";


        testClass(funClass,str);
```

However, I donot know how to invoke testClass if I want to use function object.

```
   ClassA obj;
testClass(obj.operator()(str),str); // compilation errors
```

Comment: your class function objects only take a single string parameter.

Comment: Would it be possible in your code to wrap the function calls in a class and call functors with the instances of such a class having both pointer of the function to call and the arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "functor" class is not a function pointer. However `std::function` takes constructors that will implicitly create one from a functor or function pointer.

If you are allowed to modify testClass then ideally make it more generic:

```
void testClass( std::function< void( std::string & ) > func, std::string & name )
{
   func( name );
}
```

You can then call

```
testClass( ClassA(), name );
```

If it is not going to modify the string it should probably take this parameter by const reference.

You could write delegate functions for your classes that forward them like this but I don't think that's really what you are looking for as you'd have to write one for each delegate:

Otherwise you can write a templated function like this

```
template< typename T >
void callT( std::string & name )
{
    T t;
    t( name );
}


testClass( callT< ClassA > );
```

If you are using `C++11` you can pass in a lambda function in your instance which will convert to a function pointer. (Thanks Steve Jessop for telling me this).

In this case it is a bit of a workaround as you would have to type out the lambda function for every functor class you want to use it with. (So even though the feature is there the template is possibly better).

To do it with the lambda you would do

```
testClass( []( std::string & str ){ ClassA a; a(str); }, name );
```

Note that for the lambda to be able to convert to a function it cannot take captchas, but then it wouldn't be possible to do the templated version if you needed extra data members either.

Comment: Also, non-capturing lambdas can be converted to function pointers. So you could do without the template in the last code snippet and write `testClass([](string &name) { return ClassA()(name); });`

Comment: Thank you. The problem of doing that in this case is that you essentially have to write out a new lambda for every functor class you want to use it with.

Comment: Agreed. In fact as I've stated it you have to write a lambda for each call to `testClass`, which might be even more than one per class. The whole point of lambdas is that you don't mind writing them out (at any rate, you mind less than you mind writing a named function or functor). So if you don't want to do that then of course don't use them :-)

Comment: Agreed. I like lambdas and use them a fair amount, especially as they make your code far more easily readable.

Answer (score 1):

A class instance is in general not a function pointer, but a class instance that is a lambda which does not capture anything, converts implicitly to function pointer:

```
auto const f = []( std::string& s ) { classA()( s ); };
testClass( f, "blah" );
```

Or use an ordinary named function.

Standard library algorithms can use either raw function pointer or class instance with `operator()`, because the type is templated.

---

The more general question, how to convert a possibly stateful functor object to raw function pointer, e.g. for C callback, is more interesting.

The standard library unfortunately lacks support for that.

Comment: Because I don't see how it is possible, unless the callback takes some generic pointer that can be converted into whatever you want, and is able to hold that state.

Comment: @CashCow: Your sentence starting with "Because" is bewildering. But assuming you're asking how to convert a stateful functor to a raw function pointer for use as C callback, one way is to store a pointer to the functor instance in a static variable, which the ordinary function then can use to call the functor. That's easy enough (like, trivial), but it starts getting less simple when you have an arbitrary dynamic number of functors of arbitrary types.

Comment: Right, in general you'd expect to have to generate a trampoline per instance of the converted capturing lambda, like GCC does for nested functions. I think the C++ standard is unlikely ever to require implementations to be able to do that, I may of course be wrong.

Comment: Oh yeah you can store the "state" in a global somewhere. Not re-entrant of course... When the callback takes a "generic" void * then you can make that point to anything and hold whatever state you want. In this case you can't do it other than hacking in extra info into your "string" parameter but that isn't permitted here.

If you need this for a C interface, put an extra void* parameter into the callback where you can generically hold whatever is appropriate to the callback function.

Comment: @CashCow: re "In this case you can't do it", that's meaningless.

Comment: My first comment was in response to "The more general question is", and not your answer. Obviously that wasn't clear.

It is too late to edit that comment.

What I meant was that in the case you want state and no parameter to store it, it would not be possible.

Comment: @CashCow: well it's still unclear to me what you mean, but everything in my answer, including the commentary about the more general question, and including the stuff I mentioned in comment and that Steve Jessop elaborated on, *has been done*. If you're interested in details head over to the C++ lounge and check if the good puppy is there. He attempted to make such proposal for C++11 (I'm not sure what came of it, though).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf just went to the chat, and DeadMG said there were a few workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the `testClass` function as a function template.

```
template<typename T>
void testClass(T fun, std::string& name) {
  fun(name);
}
```

Then it can accept function pointers as well as instances of function objects.

That's simpler than triggering the `std::function` machinery.

There is this flexibility in C++ function pointers where you're not forced to write `*fun()` to call the pointed-to function. You can just write `fun()`.

And by the way, you can also pass in references-to-functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a thread-local stack of function objects. This would be something like

```
template<typename Sig> struct horrible_hackery;
template<typename Ret, typename... Args> struct horrible_hackery {
    static thread_local std::stack<std::function<Ret(Args...)>> functions;
    static Ret trampoline_callback(Args... args) {
        return functions.top()(args...);
    }
    template<typename F, typename Around> static void execute_around_fptr(F f, Around a) {
        functions.push(f);
        a(&trampoline_callback);
        functions.pop();
    }
};
```

Now you can use

```
ClassA obj;
horrible_hackery<void(std::string&)>::execute_around(obj, [&](void(*fptr)(std::string&)) {
    return testclass(fptr, str);
});
```

There *is* a C++03 version of this which is even more terrible terrible hackery that you don't want to think about.

If you're truly desperate for this feature and you can't accept the purely stack-based solution above, you can download a JIT compiler for the platform of your choice like LLVM and then JIT a thunk for yourself. This is pretty extreme though.

However, these limitations and generally horrible hackery leads one to the following conclusions:

- Prefer a templated function object type if possible.
- If not possible, use std::function which handles this in the optimal possible fashion.
- Do not ever use function pointers or their even-more-evil siblings, member function pointers, unless you have some concrete requirement like dodging ABI bullets.